# Using Google ML-Kit On-Device Text Recognition in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text-recognition, google-mlkit, flutter-packages

Is it possible to use Google ML-Kit On-Device Text Recognition in Flutter?  All of the tutorials and resources I am finding online are all `firebase_ml_vision`, but I am looking for one that uses the no-cost OCR from Google ML-Kit.  How would I do this in Flutter?

Comment: Hi, there is no flutter plugin developed for the standalone ML Kit currently. There used to be one created for Firebase ML Kit on device Apis. You can check this to see if it still works: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_ml_vision/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemlvision

Comment: Hello, have a look at this flutter plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit

Comment: But is this package also available when deploying to the web, or just on mobile operating systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Sayan Nath said you can use `mlkit`, but I think the better choice would be [`google_ml_kit`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit), the firebase team who have worked on firebase_ml_vision also recommended using it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes surely you can use this package [https/pub.dev/packages/mlkit](https://pub.dev/packages/mlkit) this is google's mlkit. OCR has also support for both ios and android. Happy Coding ;)

Comment: This link appears to be out-of-date. It's incompatible with Dart 3, and there's a new version of the toolkit (available by following the link).

Answer (score 1):

use this package https://pub.dev/packages/camera_google_ml_vision
It's exactly the same in terms of how to use firebase_ml_vision

Answer (score 1):

**ML Kit for Text Recognition**

Follow the installation of Google ML Kit (https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit). (Flutter 2.8)

Set this thing up

```
bool hasImage = false;
File? image;
TextDetector textDetector = GoogleMlKit.vision.textDetector();
String? imagePath;
String scanText = '';
```

To get the image, use image picker: https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

```
Future getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
      if (image == null) return;
      final imageTemporary = File(image.path);
      setState(() {
        this.image = imageTemporary;
        imagePath = imageTemporary.path;
        debugPrint(imagePath);
        hasImage = true;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Failed to pick image: $e');
    }
  }
```

Code for getting the text from the image

```
Future getText(String path) async {
    final inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(path);
    final RecognisedText recognisedText =
        await textDetector.processImage(inputImage);

    for (TextBlock block in recognisedText.blocks) {
      for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
        for (TextElement element in line.elements) {
          setState(() {
            scanText = scanText + '  ' + element.text;
            debugPrint(scanText);
          });
        }
        scanText = scanText + '\n';
      }
    }
  }
```

Call the `getText` function and pass the image path. `getText(imagePath)`.